# is it possible to let people open scroll menu only on Google sheet with VIEW permissions?

Tags: validation, google-sheets, drop-down-menu, permissions

as the title says, I want to share my Google sheet with some people but when only setting VIEW permissions they can't open the scroll menus like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, this is not yet possible in Google Sheets. scroll menus (dropdowns) are visible only to those who are able to edit the spreadsheet

Comment: that's sad :( hopefully they add something for it